# problem to write text in a fixed position

Tags: html, css

I am just a beginner here. I want to make a simple web page using html and css. I have made the header, left content, as well as right content and footer.

In left content, I want to write some normal descriptive text. I have used `ul` and `li` tags using `text-align:justify`. But the problem is this: texts are over the right content of the page. I want them to be on a new line rather then over to the right side. What should I do now?

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="left_content">
            <ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy   nibh commodo consequat.</li></ul>
            <a href="#"> Read More</a>

            <ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh commodo consequat.</li></ul>
            <a href="#"> Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div id="right_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

and css code :

```
#left_content ul li {
padding:10px 0 0 0px;
font:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
color:#000000;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: This might help solving the problem http://jsfiddle.net/cqxGS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give your `#left_content` a width

```
#left_content{
    width:200px;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/p3ApG/

Comment: thanks a lot, Mr. Jason Gennaro. its absolutely working......:) Many many thanks to you.

Comment: Super @webrider! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not give the li an explicit width ?

```
#left_content ul li {
    padding:10px 0 0 0px;
    font:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#000000;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLRw6/)